# Recursion $f(n) = 3f(n-1) - 4f(n-3)$ with $f(0) = 1$ , $f(1) = -3$ , $f(2) = 2$

Tags: recursion

How can one solve the recursion

$$f(n) = 3f(n-1) - 4f(n-3)$$

The start values are

$f(0) = 1$

$f(1) = -3$

$f(2) = 2$

I tried to find a general pattern to prove it with induction, but I can't find one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use generating functions:
$$g(x):=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f(n)x^n$$
So we have that
$$g(x)=f(0)x^0+f(1)x^1+f(2)x^2+\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n)x^n$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n)x^n$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+\sum_{n \geq 3}(3f(n-1)-4f(n-3))x^n$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n-1)x^n-4\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n-3)x^n$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n-1)x^{n-1}x-4\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n-3)x^{n-3}x^3$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3x\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n-1)x^{n-1}-4x^3\sum_{n \geq 3}f(n-3)x^{n-3}$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3x\sum_{n \geq 2}f(n)x^{n}-4x^3\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f(n)x^{n}$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3x\left(\sum_{n \geq 2}f(n)x^{n}+f(0)x^0+f(1)x^1-f(0)x^0-f(1)x^1\right)-4x^3\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f(n)x^{n}$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3x\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f(n)x^{n}-f(0)x^0-f(1)x^1\right)-4x^3\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f(n)x^{n}$$
$$=1-3x+2x^2+3x\left(g(x)-1+3x\right)-4x^3g(x)$$
So:
$$g(x)=1-3x+2x^2+3x\left(g(x)-1+3x\right)-4x^3g(x)$$
$$g(x)=1-3x+2x^2-3x+9x^2+3xg(x)-4x^3g(x)$$
$$g(x)(1-3x+4x^3)=1-6x+11x^2$$
$$g(x)=\frac{1-6x+11x^2}{1-3x+4x^3}$$
Doing partial fraction decomposition on $g$ (I'll leave it for you):
$$g(x)=\frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{1/2}{(2x-1)^2}+\frac{3/2}{2x-1}$$
And now we can use taylor series:
$$g(x)=2\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{(-1)^nx^n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}2^nx^n(1+n)\right)-\frac{3}{2}\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}2^nx^n\right)$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}x^n\left(2(-1)^n+\frac{1+n}{2}2^n-\frac{3}{2}2^n\right)$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}x^n\left(2(-1)^n+(n-2)2^{n-1}\right)$$
But the coefficient of $x^n$ in $g(x)$ is $f(n)$:
$$f(n)=2(-1)^n+(n-2)2^{n-1}$$
And if you worry about the validity of the manipulations, you can check the result with induction, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the general method. For
$$f(n) = 3f(n-1) - 4f(n-3)$$ the characteristic equation is
$$r^3=3r^2-4$$ $r=-1$ is an obvious root. Now use division to get the quadratic and then the two other roots.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP will know how to write down the solution explicitly from the characteristic equation if they didn't know the method themselves (in which case they wouldn't ask the question, I presume).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(n)=a^n$.

This gives the following equation:

$$a^n-3a^{n-1}+4a^{n-3}=0$$

$$a^{n-3}(a^3-3a^2+4)=0$$

$$a^3-3a^2+4=0\tag{1}$$

One solution is obviously $a=-1$. Equation (1) can be now factorized in the following way:

$$(a+1)(a^2-4a+4)=0$$
$$(a+1)(a-2)^2=0$$

So we have three roots with two of them being equal:

$$a_1=-1,a_2=a_3=2$$

It can be shown that the general solution $f(n)$ is a sum of partial solutions of the form $C_ia_i^n$ if the multiplicity of the solution is 1. If you have a solution with multiplicity 2, the partial solution has the form $(C_i+C_{i+1}n)a_i^n$. In general if you have a solution with multiplicity k, the partial solution will be:

$$(C_i+C_{i+1}n+...+C_{i+k-1}n^{k-1})a_i^n$$

In our case, the solution is of the form:

$$f(n)=C_1(-1)^n+(C_2+C_3n)2^n$$

Constants $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ can be obtained from initial conditions:

$$f(0)=C_1+C_2=1$$

$$f(1)=-C_1+2C_2+2C_3=-3$$

$$f(2)=C_1+4C_2+8C_3=2$$

The solutions are: $C_1=2$, $C_2=-1$ and $C_3={1 \over 2}$

So the final solution is:

$$f(n)=(-1)^n\times 2+(-1+\frac n2)\times 2^n$$

$$f(n)=(-1)^n\times 2+(n-2)\times 2^{n-1}$$

$$\boxed{f(n)=2\times[(-1)^n+(n-2)\times 2^{n-2}]}$$

To understand all the details you need to read some theory and a good starting point could be [here](http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf).